# Белый экран. PHP

Tags: php, html

Добрый вечер. Дело вот в чем. Значит установил я XAMPP и запустил. Компьютер пустой, т.е. антивируса не стоит, Skype нет. 
Все запущено, т.е. никакие программы не мешают. Далее перейдем на localhost.
Попробуем вызвать phpinfo().
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает, а теперь создам html документ с таким кодом :

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "affsfasfasfas";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

И получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Белый лист. Сохраняю я там, где нужно и все такое, в чем проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код возвращаемой страницы (`Правая кнопка мыши на странице → Просмотр кода страницы`). Если там пусто, то приведите содержимое следующих файлов: `httpd.conf`, `access.log` и `error.log`.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что файл info.php с содержимым `<?php phpinfo();` возвращает результат, а обращение к index.php с приведённым вами содержимым даёт белый экран?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию, html файлы не обрабатываются PHP, и в целом запихивать PHP код в HTML файл это неправильно.

PHP код должен находиться в файлах .php, html должен быть в .html (я тут не упоминаю различные форматы шаблонизаторов)

Следовательно проблема в том, что у вас браузер обрабатывает строку phpinfo() заключенную в теги PHP, поэтому ничего не выводиться.

Comment: phpinfo() и вот этот код : <html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "affsfasfasfas";
?>
</body>
</html> 
у меня в разных файлах. 
Даже если я поменяю с html на php , то все равно будет белый экран.

Comment: @tttyyyrrrryyy Он у вас в принципе должен быть в формате .php, а не html. При белом экране откройте исходный код страницы и посмотрите, не вывелось ли туда что-нибудь, браузер не выводит кривой код без просмотра исходного кода. Если там абсолютно пусто, идите в логи и смотрите ошибки интерпретатора.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте расширение вашего файла с html  на php и всё заработает.